# vagrant up error not working

Tags: php, macos, vagrant, homestead

I tried to install Laravel Homestead on my computer.

I have followed to the documentation and I got it up working yesterday.

However I left my laptop on sleep and I tried to run vagrant provision and I receive this weird error.

```
Jafars-iMac:Homestead jafarsalami$ vagrant provision

/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 18 > column 5 (Psych::SyntaxError)

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:252:in `load'

from /Users/jafarsalami/Homestead/Vagrantfile:28:in `block in <top (required)>'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in load'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `each'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `each'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:810:in `new'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:810:in `vagrantfile'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:556:in `host'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:543:in `hook'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in `unload'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/bin/vagrant:141:in `ensure in <main>'

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/bin/vagrant:141:in `<main>'
```

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: I have added my Homestead.yaml file as it might help in solving this problem.
My Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/homestead.test/public



databases:
      - homestead
-     – somesite_db
+     - somesite_db

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: Did you try to `vagrant suspend`, `vagrant up` or worst case, `vagrant destroy -f`, `vagrant up`?

Comment: @balintant yep noting works

Comment: Is it throwing any errors when you just send `vagrant`? In that case might be an issue in the generated `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: I'd be interested in your `Homestead.yml` for syntax issues.

Comment: @balintant yep there is the same error

Comment: Must be the configuration file. Please append your Homestead.yml (censore sensitive parts) to your question.

Comment: Also, may you give me a `git diff --stat` from `~/Homestead`?

Comment: @balintant I have added the Homestead.yaml file

Comment: @balintant nothing come up when I enter git diff --stat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Homestead.yaml` on line :23 you have an invalid hyphen. See that it's a bit longer than a normal one.

```
  databases:
      - homestead
-     – somesite_db
+     - somesite_db
```

Comment: @jafar-salami any luck?

Comment: no I have added the code you told me to add on the question.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: for some reason "sometime_db" throw an error because of the underscore.

Comment: I don't know what it was in my case, but certainly there was some kind of syntax error in my `Homestead.yaml` file. What I did was to overwrite it (reset it) with `bash init.sh` (on MacOS) and then retype again and carefully my sites and database one by one and `vagrant provision` for each one. Now it works. It is indeed painful to either install / update (actually reinstall new version) of Laravel Homestead, Man!