# Laravel setup - running vagrant gives parsing error '[]=': string not matched

Tags: laravel, vagrant, yaml

I'm following this [guide](https://www.danwalker.com/setting-up-a-laravel-homestead-box/) to get Laravel up and running on my CentOS 7 VM, and have got to step 6- Composer Setup. It says to `cd` into the 'Homestead' directory, then run `vagrant up`, followed by `vagrant ssh`.

Currently, when I run `vagrant up`, I get an error that says:

> C:/.../psych.rb:377:in 'parse': (): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 13 column 5 (Psych::SyntaxError)

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277976/vagrant-up-error-not-working) question, and the answer seems to suggest that one of the hyphens is too long in the `Homestead.yaml` file (i.e. it's double hyphen)... I had a look, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me.

My `Homestead.yaml` file is as follows:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
     to: /home/vagrant/code
     type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
     to: /home/vagrant/code/public

    - map homestead.app
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Anyone know why I can't run `vagrant up`? What else can I do to fix this?

**Edit**

So, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104917/how-to-fix-the-yaml-syntax-error-did-not-find-expected-indicator-while-pars) answer, and it seems this issue was not because of a double hyphen anywhere in my yaml file, it was actually because a couple of the lines below the ones starting with a hyphen were tabbed, rather than spaced, and I was also missing the multi-line string indicator `|`.

After changing the relevant parts of my yaml file to include `|`, and changing the tabs to spaces, the

> did not find expected '-' indicator

error was resolved:

```
folders:
    - |
     map: ~/code
     to: /home/vagrant/code
     type: "nfs"

sites:
    - |
     map: homestead.test
     to: /home/vagrant/code/public

    - |
     map homestead.app
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

However, when I now try to run `vagrant up`, I get another error that says:

> C:/Users/.../homestead.rb:213:in `[]=': string not matched (IndexError)

I don't understand what this error is showing, as I can't see the `'[]=':` characters anywhere in my yaml file... anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add :(colon) after map in your yaml file before `homestead.app`

That's what causing this error. This might be late response but in general When Homestead.ymal has some syntax error, `vagrant up` will fail with this type of errors.